# Is it possible to change the format of the numbers in the msoElementDataTableWithLegendKeys?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to change the format of the numbers in the `msoElementDataTableWithLegendKeys`?

That's the legend that appears under the graphs, with numbers.

But I can not change the format. 
I just see 845845 and i would like to see 845.845 for example.

Comment: I think it take only the source range format.

Comment: Like @Mohammed said, you'll have to format the source data. You can't apply a different format to the data table!

Comment: If understand your question correctly then i think what you want to do is apply custom number format to chart label, is that right?

Comment: you're right, one should change the data source. i am trying it, but the functions format as well as formatnumber returns strings. any help?

Comment: yep, next step is to apply custom number, for example, 0,8K and 1,2M. thanks a lot!

Comment: I am truly lost. I have a graph with a table legend. In order to change the format of the numbers, that appear in the table legend, i need to change the format source. In order to change the format source, i can use the functions format and format number. Both of them return strings. That means, i can not represent strings in the graphs.

is there something that i am missing? why i can't just change the format of a number, why excel changes it into strings? 

thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this, what i have done is record a macro to add "," so that number 10000 will appear as 10,000 on Chart Label. I have recorded this macro using macro recorder, you need to update this according to your need.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. in the axis you can change the format easily, even custom format. the problem is the table of the legend. there you can't change the format, you can just change the source format.
here i have the problem. functions FORMAT and FORMATNUMBER change the number into strings, and then i can not represent a graph. I would appreciate some help in this regard.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question. I don't know if there is a way to format chart legend.

Comment: As everbody else said in comments above, i looks like you can't change DataTable option using VBA. But you can change DataLabel format which displays on chart using VBA.